# Obtain domain of computer

Tags: sharepoint, dns

i am using a sharepoint portal over a computer. how i can obtain domain of that computer.

Comment: Do you have its IP address? What platform are you working on?

Comment: Ambiguous question, are you programatically looking for the domain the computer is attached to?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own WebPart and that WebPart can utilize System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain with code that looks like -

```
Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
output.write( domain.Name );
```

Something like that should work.